# Vulcanizing doesn't seem to be doing anything

Tags: polymer

I was under the impression that if I vulcanized my index.html, it would extract and concatenate my html imports. Here's a snippet from my index:

```
<!doctype html>
<html unresolved>
<head>

  <base href="/">
  <script src="/assets/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
  <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

  <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-icon/core-icon.html">
  <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-item/core-item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
```

and so forth. I am including just the polymer bits I need. I don't have any self-defined custom elements (I'm just assembling a UI from core- and paper- components).

I was under the impression that some combination of --inline and other flags would result in a very long index.html that no longer directly imported the bower_component files. I could be wrong about that, I suppose, but that's my goal. It's not that big of a deal; I am not even sure that the correct answer here is making my index.html huge in order to avoid 20 extra loads, especially with caching and all that. Still, there's no way to test this without having an inline version to test.

Edit:
I'm running vulcanize in the root of my built dist directory:

```
dist/
  index.html
  bower_components/
```

and it runs, I've tried with --inline and --csp and both, and it basically just spits index.html back out into vulcanized.html. If I do --strip, it strips whitespace, but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried to Vulcanize my `Index.html`, I always have an `elements.html` file which has all my imports and I finally import the `elements.html` in my Main file.

Whenever I try to Vulcanize my `elements.html` file it works as expected by concatenating all the Elements' definitions into one file for decreasing the number of http requests the browser has to make.

The problem might be that you are using the very latest version of `Volcan` which has been reworked on and the `--csp` feature has been moved to a standalone cli app by itself and the `--strip` has also be moved to the `html-minifier` app.

You might want to check that out.
https://github.com/PolymerLabs/crisper
https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I figured it out- I was using `href="/bower_components/core-icon/core-icon.html"` when I should have been using `href="bower_components/core-icon/core-icon.html"`.

Note the lack of the leading slash. Now I just need to figure out how to wire it up so it can find bower_components properly.